# Running a compute intensive application Service CPU usage goes very high

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, services, cpu-usage, resource-monitor

My compute intensive image processing application, when run (on Windows 8.1 HP Laptop) gets the CPU to run at over 100% as expected, but at the same time the Service CPU usage goes up to over 50% (very unexpected) and the services listed that are using a lot of CPU do not make sense at all.

My compute intensive image processing application, 1st grabs a few thousand frames of video data from a camera and then does image processing on the data.
During the grabing of frames some pre-computation (histogram, min/max, etc.) is computed on the frames as they come in but the bulk of processing is done after. Grab takes about 10 seconds and computation 13-20 seconds.
I use OMP with Visual Studio 2013 for all computations to distribute to all 8 CPU on my laptop.

Here is what the Resource Monitor shows:

[Resource Monitor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myUf6.jpg)

When I replaced the compute intensive functions with `Sleep` the CPU dropped to close to 0 and Service CPU also dropped to close to 0, so it is not the OMP, threads, semaphores, etc. that are causing the Service CPU to go high as those still happen like before.

My questions are:

1. How come the Service CPU goes high just because my threads are computing something?
2. Why such services as "DigitalPersona Aut..", "Win.. Defendeer..", "Win.. Phone..", "IP Helper", etc. get involved in heavy computation tasks.
3. Is 50% CPU wasted on needles Services tasks?

Anyone have any idea or knowledge about this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try examining what these services are doing, using a tool such as
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer),
although this requires some knowledge of Windows API.

You could also start reducing the problem by disabling some services:

- The DigitalPersona service can be disabled if you are not using the
  fingerprint scanner for login. If you have HP SimplePass installed,
  you could then uninstall it.
- The IpOverUsbSvc service is usually installed by the Windows SDK.
  It could be disabled if you are not using the computer for phoning.

I can however understand Defender being more active when the computer is
very active, as it is tracing everything that goes on.
You could perhaps create an exception for the folder where this program
is located, and perhaps this would calm it down somewhat.